# Change C and C++ compiler on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, gcc

I needed to use OpenMP and Xcode command line tools come with gcc version 4.2.something so I wanted to upgrade to gcc version 4.8. I have gcc4.8 installed. I did this -

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/g++
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
```

Similar link for g++. Now there IS a gcc link created in /usr/bin. I can see gcc in /usr/bin when I do
    $ ls -la /usr/bin

and I can also see the correct symlink when I do

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep gcc
```

It points to gcc-4.8.

However, the system simply ignores gcc. It is as if it doesn't exist there. /usr/bin is in my PATH variable. However, gcc [tab complete] does not show up.

```
$ gcc
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

Compiling any C program now uses cc located in /usr/bin/cc. I don't get it. I simply removed the current symlink gcc had with xcode CLTools and made a new one. What did I do wrong considering I really did very little?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the args to your ln command the wrong way round?

Comment: What happens when you type `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` on the command line?

Comment: I'm assuming it's not found. ln -s doesn't require the target to exist. You probably have a symlink at `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` which points to `/usr/bin/gcc`, which is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax to create the symbolic link is incorrect: the first argument to `ln` is where you want the link to point *to*.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
```

From the man page for `ln`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
     ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
```

This is slightly confusing, as "source" and "target" could be interpreted either way (i.e. is `target_file` the target of the link or the target of the `ln` command?).  The man page later clarifies this:

> Given one or two arguments, ln creates a link to an existing file source_file.  If target_file is given, the link has that name;
>        target_file may also be a directory in which to place the link; otherwise it is placed in the current directory.  If only the
>        directory is specified, the link will be made to the last component of source_file.

Comment: That worked. I don't know why I was doing it the other way round. I don't know if I should ask this as a separate question but how do I force cmake to use gcc and g++ instead of Clang? I have the symlinks correctly set up now but cmake chooses to use clang 4.2 which also does not support OpenMP so it doesn't really do me any good.

I have tried exporting the C and CXX flags and gcc -v shows up the correct version so I know it's there.